# What steps are necessary to add a new peer to an organization of hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I’m learning to build a network with Hyperlegder Fabric because I have developed a network with Hyperledger Composer and the next step is to build the production network. I have started to build the first-network sample and works. I have added Org3 with 2 peers to sample and it works.

And now I want to add more peers, for example peer2.org1.example.com so I have edited files in order to create the peer2 and it is created, but when the script.sh tries to join to channel, it launches an error:

> Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer
>       Caused by: x509: certificate is valid for peer1.org1.example.com, peer1, not peer2.org1.example.com

So, What have I done incorrectly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by generating the crypto material (using [cryptogen extends](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/cryptogen-commands.html#the-cryptogen-extend-command)) for the new peer, spawning the new peer and made that peer to join the existing channel on the network to sync-up.

You can find the complete guide at

[Extending Hyperledger Fabric Network: Adding a new peer](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)

Answer (score 2):

When you adding a new peer to the network you need to make sure to properly setup all related crypto material underlined for that new peer. First of all make sure to add information about new peer into `crypto-config.yaml` file and to use `cryptogen` tool to generate keys and certificates for new peer. Next you need to setup configuration before starting the peer to point to the relevant crypto material for example configuration for peer0 of org2:

```
  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
```

where it's inherited from `base/peer-base.yaml` file:

```
services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

to wrap it up, you need to make sure to config proper MSP ID and path to tls certificates. In your case your new peer simply tries to reuse crypto material of another peer.

Comment: I haven't updated the path of tls certificastes. Thank you!