# add new peer in hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

im a noobie in hyperledger fabric . i downloaded a sample project 'tuna app' and started working on it. However they only use 1 peer , i tried to add multiple peers by adding one more fabric-peer container , but not able make peers join the channel 
this is the code segment i dont understand , can someone explain what this means

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

this is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic
  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 5000:7051
      - 5001:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer.example.com:7050
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
    #depends_on:
    #  - orderer.example.com
    #  - peer0.org1.example.com
    #  - couchdb
```

i tried to add peer1 container ,
what am i doing wrong , someone please help me

Comment: [Answered Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218112/what-steps-are-necessary-to-add-a-new-peer-to-an-organization-of-hyperledger-fab?rq=1) Here is a high level answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What steps are necessary to add a new peer to an organization of hyperledger fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218112/what-steps-are-necessary-to-add-a-new-peer-to-an-organization-of-hyperledger-fab)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by generating the crypto material (using cryptogen extends) for the new peer, spawning the new peer and made that peer to join the existing channel on the network to sync-up. You will also need a new docker-compose file for the definition of new peer.

You can find the complete guide at

[Extending Hyperledger Fabric Network: Adding a new peer](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)